# Can anyOne help me to translate these from openGLES1.1 to openGLES2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

//I have no idea about this, can anyone help me
//texture type is CCTexture2D, _Vertices type is CGPoint*,_Coords type is CGPoint*

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _Vertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _Coords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nVertices);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name); glUniform1i(/*insert texture uniform*/0, 1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

glUniform4f(/*insert color uniform*/0, 1, 1, 1, 1);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _Vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _Coords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nVertices);

//glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

//glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
```

This should be more or less an ES2 equivalent. I hope it will help you enough to finish the "translation".